# is PHP redirection seo friendly?

Tags: php, redirect, header, seo

I'm using this to redirect to the home page if the post doesn't exist:

```
if($_GET['id'] > mysql_num_rows($total_rows)){
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
    header("Location: ".site_url."/"); 
    exit(); 
}
```

is this SEO friendly?

Comment: SEO is speculation, and thus off-topic.

Comment: Mario I don't agree with you. I am not SEO Expert, but I don't beleave that is speculation too (I rate up again)! Any way that kind of redirection is correct and SEO Friendly.

Comment: @MerianosNikos: Did not downvote. We can only answer the known technical part here, which is that redirects work and are honored by search engines. If this influences ranking (SEO) is entirely a guessing game, not a technical question. Such inquiries might be on-topic for Webmasters.SE however.

Comment: how come you are comparing an id with number of rows? it makes no sense for me

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel posts are stored in a database with an auto-incrementing id, posts are displayed by id `?id=12` if it's greater than the total number of rows then the post doesn't exist at all.

Comment: hehe, you are doing it ENTIRELY wrong :)

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel then how should I be doing it?

Comment: @jc Just select the post from the database as requested (`SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = ...`), if it doesn't exist, show a 404 error page. Certainly don't select *all* posts and count them in PHP. Autoincrementing ids also don't necessarily correspond to the total number of posts in the db. What if you delete a post in the middle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A 301 redirect is the wrong thing to do here. You should issue a 404 Not Found with a nice error page that explains the status to the user (including a *link* to your homepage or anywhere else) or similarly a 410 Gone if the content existed before. A 301 is incorrect here and may or may not be SEO friendly; a 4xx status is certainly more correct. Whether this status is issued through PHP or any other means is irrelevant.

Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http_status_codes

Comment: Thanks for clarying that out (y)

Answer (score 1):

yes this should be SEO friendly. [see redirect section](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Answer (score 1):

A bit offtopic to the literal question, but too long for the comment.

1. There can be deleted entries, so, the actual id would be always bigger than number of entries.
2. This is wrong way for counting entries anyway. you have to select only number itself, not ALL the date from the table, select `count(*)` instead.
3. Though you need no such number either. Why such a vague verification "if such post exists in general", while you can check this post's existence itself, by requesting it itself? Not to mention thay you will need it's contents anyway?